# How can I get integer values from binary file

Tags: python

I have some files they look like this with hex/octal dump:

hexdump file:

```
0000000 0002 0000 0c3e 0000 0ac5 0000          
000000c
```

od file:

```
0000000 000002 000000 006076 000000 005305 000000
0000014
```

I dont know really what this "000002" and "0000014" is good for but, I know I need this "006076" and "005305" as interger value, so I did this in python2:

```
hex(006076)
'0xc3e'

int(0xc3e)
3134
```

I don't know really how I should open/and read this file/values in python2...

simple open/read the file looks like this:

```
x = open("file", "rb")
x.read()
'\x02\x00\x00\x00>\x0c\x00\x00\xc5\n\x00\x00'
```

Comment: `0000000 000002` is one value, by the way, but try to `open` the file, at least, and read it

Comment: Just because the file contents are binary strings, doesn't mean you need to open the file as binary

Comment: You're getting completely different contents when you're opening the file in Python. Are you really sure you're opening the same file that you hexdumped earlier? Either you're opening a different file, or something has changed the file in the meantime.

Comment: you where right, I picked the wrong file, sry for that

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to use `struct.unpack`.

```
>>> import struct
>>> struct.unpack("4x H 2x H 2x", '\x02\x00\x00\x00>\x0c\x00\x00\xc5\n\x00\x00')
(3134, 2757)
```

The format string used as the first argument tells `unpack` to ignore the first 4 bytes, then unpack the next two bytes as an integer, ignore 2 more bytes, unpack another 2-byte integer, and ignore the last 2 bytes. This assumes the byte string uses the same endianness as your machine's default; see the documentation for the `struct` module for more details.

Answer (score 0):

The functions `hex(int)` and `oct(int)` take an integer in base 10 (decimal) and convert it into a string that looks like a number in base 8 or base 16 (hex or octal).  The function `int()` just takes a string that looks like a number and converts it from a string into an integer in base 10.

You should be able to use the `int()` function to do this with the format `int([string representing number], [base of number])`.  Here's how it works:

In a base n number system, the value of the number is `(1st digit) * n^0 + (2nd digit) * n^1 + (3rd digit) ^ n^2 + ...`.  For example, if you have the number 472 in octal (base 8), you could calculate the value like so:

```
2 * 8^0  +  7 * 8^1  +  4 * 8^2
2 * (1)  +  7 * (8)  +  4 * (64)
2 + 56 + 256
314
```

So 472 in octal is equivalent to 314 in decimal.  To make a function out of this, I'd do something like this:

```
def convertToDecimal(number, baseOfNumber):
    counter = 0
    for c in reversed(number)
        newNumber += (c * (baseOfNumber ^ counter))
        counter += 1
    return newNumber
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: FWIW, the `int` constructor takes an optional `base` arg. Try this: `int('472',8)`.

Comment: Well, that's a lot simpler than my answer.  Thank you!

Comment: Edited the answer to reflect that.